# split string by last space on data table

Tags: r, string, split, data.table

I have a data table with 2 columns:

```
             term  freq
1:    a arena tour    1
2: a available why    1
3:     a backup in    1
4:       a bad ass    1
5:     a bad chick    1
```

and I would like to split the "term" column by the last space, for example:

```
         termA  termB freq
1:     a arena   tour    1
2: a available    why    1
3:    a backup     in    1
4:       a bad  chick    1
```

I tried using "str" (code bellow), which works on a string alone but doesnt work on a data.date (it seems t obe using the same index on all rows)

```
data.table (termA = substr(dt_n3$term, 1, rev(gregexpr("\\ ", dt_n3$term)[[1]])[1]-1),
                         termB = substr(dt_n3$term, rev(gregexpr("\\ ", dt_n3$term)[[1]])[1], 1000),
                         freq = dt_n3$freq)
```

Anyway, I don't think this is the best approach.
Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sub` it may be achieved in two steps.

```
dt = data.table(term = c("a arena tour","a available why","a bad ass"), freq=1)

# erase last part
dt[, termA := sub(" [^ ]*$", "", term)]

# erase first part
dt[, termB := sub(".* ", "", term)]
```

Answer (score 7):

You could try the `tstrsplit` function from [`data.table` v 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
DT[, paste0('term', LETTERS[1:2]) := tstrsplit(term, ' (?=[^ ]*$)',
                                     perl=TRUE)][, term:=NULL][]
#   freq       termA termB
#1:    1     a arena  tour
#2:    1 a available   why
#3:    1    a backup    in
#4:    1       a bad   ass
#5:    1       a bad chick
```

#### data

```
DT <- data.table(term= c("a arena tour", "a available why", 
      "a backup in", "a bad ass", "a bad chick"), freq=1)
```

---

Slightly modified version in which you can do assignment and deletion in the same statement:

```
cols = c("term", paste0("term", LETTERS[1:2]))
DT[, (cols) := c(list(NULL), tstrsplit(term, ' (?=[^ ]*$)', perl=TRUE))]
```

Assigning `NULL` to `term` deletes that column.

Comment: akrun, thanks, nothing special there - concatenate to result in a list... had to pass `NULL` for `term`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringi` package:

```
x <- c("ala ma kota", "this is text")
stri_locate_last_fixed(x, " ")
##      start end
## [1,]     7   7
## [2,]     8   8
splitHere <- stri_locate_last_fixed(x, " ")
stri_sub(x, to= splitHere[,1]-1)
## [1] "ala ma"  "this is"
stri_sub(x, from= splitHere[,1]+1)
## [1] "kota" "text"
cbind(stri_sub(x, to= splitHere[,1]-1), stri_sub(x, from=splitHere[,1]+1))
##      [,1]      [,2]  
## [1,] "ala ma"  "kota"
## [2,] "this is" "text"
```